# Understanding POSIX Threads

Tags: multithreading, posix, pthreads

I have some confusion with POSIX Threads, I want to know if my understanding of Pthreads is proper,

According to me its a layer above the native layer which helps in dealing with multithreading.
It provides a common syntax, which helps while porting from one OS to other.
It internally takes care of the various OS specific constructs.

Please let me know if I am wrong and add points which I have missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, pthread is just an API, like rest of POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

One important point here is that POSIX library is for *nix OSes and not for others (e.g. Windows). Although some implementation of pthreads library is available for windows, it is not exhaustive.